# How can I order by ForeignKey field itself in django without join?

Tags: django, orm

So I have a model `MyModel` with a ForeignKey field `fkfield`. And i need to do something like this (simplified):

```
MyModel.objects.values_list('id', 'fkfield').order_by('fkfield')
```

For example I want to `groupby` them further by `fkfield` so I need my objects to be sorted by this field. And the only thing I will use later is `fkfield_id`. I mean I dont need any data from related model.

But django performs a join sql query (as described in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#order-by)) and uses related model's `ordering`. The same happens if i explicitly try to order by `id`:

```
MyModel.objects.values_list('id', 'fkfield').order_by('fkfield__id')
```

and I get:

```
SELECT `mymodel`.`id`, 
       `mymodel`.`fkfield_id` 
  FROM `mymodel` 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN `related_table` 
            ON ( `mymodel`.`fkfield_id` = `related_table`.`id` ) 
ORDER BY 
       `related_table`.`id` ASC
```

What i really expect is:

```
SELECT `id`, 
       `fkfield_id` 
  FROM `mymodel` 
ORDER BY 
       `fkfield_id` ASC
```

But I can't find a way to do it. `.order_by('fkfield_id')` raises exception that says that there is no such a field.

I managed to get things work using `extra` but I can't understand why such a simple and obvious behaviour can't be used without hacks. Or maybe i missed smth?

**UPDATE: models.py**

```
class Producer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)

class Collection(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    producer = models.ForeignKey('Producer')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)

print Collection.objects.values_list('producer', 'id').order_by('producer').query
>>> SELECT `catalog_collection`.`producer_id`, `catalog_collection`.`id`
>>> FROM `catalog_collection`
>>> INNER JOIN `catalog_producer` ON
>>> (`catalog_collection`.`producer_id` = `catalog_producer`.`id`)
>>> ORDER BY `catalog_producer`.`name` ASC
```

Comment: I wonder why you want to order by fkfield_id as this is most of the time only a technical value and therefore I see no benefit to use it for ordering? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
.order_by('fkfield')
```

My query is

```
Post.objects.values('author', 'id').order_by('author')
```

as sql:

```
SELECT "blogs_post"."author_id", 
       "blogs_post"."id" 
FROM "blogs_post" 
ORDER BY "blogs_post"."author_id" ASC
```

**UPDATE**

Kind of messy solution:

```
MyModel.objects.extra(select={'fkfield_id': 'fkfield_id'})\
       .values_list('id', 'fkfield_id')\
       .order_by('fkfield_id')
```

Comment: I've shown my models. As I said join query is performed when related model `producer` have `ordering` attribute in its Meta class. If I remove it I get the same query as yours but I need it in some other places so it can't be a solution.

Comment: Thanks, I've done exactly the same as i wrote in my question :) It seems to me that it can be treated as a bug coz we can order by id witout join by default but we cant reproduce this behaviour if related model has ordering defined.